# Golang package is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/packageName)

Tags: go, module

Hi could someone help me run my main.go: `go run main.go` ?

There are two folders, which are next to each other:

proj1 folder has main.go, go.mod

package1 folder has package1.go, go.mod, utility.go

inside of main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "package1"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    y := package1.Struct1{
        v: "1",
    }
    z := package1.isTrue()
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

inside my package folder: package1.go

```
package package1

type Package1 struct {}

func (a *Package1) IsTrue() bool {
    return true
}
```

My Go version: go1.15.2 linux/amd64

My Go env settings:

```
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/user1/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/user1/.config/go/env"
GOMODCACHE="/mnt/sda5/gopath/pkg/mod"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/mnt/sda5/gopath"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
...
```

I tried :
go install, go build ... results no error inside the package folder

go mod vendor, go run main.go, go get -u package1 ... result in the same message when run inside the proj1 folder:

package package1 is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/package1)

The VS Code Go Plugin Linter shows no problem.
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: This is not how modules are used, or how a package is compiled. [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) walks through this same type of example, step by step.

Comment: If you install the latest version of Go correctly, I doubt you will need to look at or change any environment vars. In other words, I think the accepted answer is mostly obsolete. The @JimB recommended link is obsolete as well. As of 2022, https://go.dev/doc/ is probably a good starting point.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To solve the error i was facing `package package1 is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/package1)`

I had to ensure the environment variables were correctly configured.

I added those lines in the `bashrc` file:

```
export GO111MODULE=on
#GOPATH MUST BE OUTSIDE OF GOROOT directory!!!
export GOPATH=/mnt/sda1/programming/gopath
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

I loaded the `bashrc` file in the terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now i can execute following procedure to program with the Go language.

Make a new `main` folder...
Inside this `main` folder:
make `main.go` file begin with `package main`

Run the command below:

```
go mod init main
```

make another folder with the new package name: e.g. `package1`

inside the `package1` folder:
make all files with `package package1` in its 1st line ... but DO NOT MAKE MOD FILE inside this package folder!!!

in your `main.go`, you can import that package and use it

```
import "main/package1"
y := package1.Struct1{a: 1, b: 2,...}
z := y.func1()
```

Answer (score 12):

This page is the top search result for...

> package xxxxx is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/xxxxx)

In my case, I was trying:

`go build mything`

That gave me the error. The solution was simple, I needed to be more specific:

`go build mything.go`

Answer (score 0):

This page is the top search result for...

> package xxxxx is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/xxxxx)

In my case, my file name was 'hello world.go' but when I tried 'go run hello world.go' it gave me the error.

The solution was simple, if your file name has a blank space you have to write it in your terminal as 'go run hello\ world.go'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).