# How should I resolve this import problem with gorilla/mux?

Tags: go, gorilla

could not import github.com/gorilla/mux (cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of
C:\Program Files\Go\src\github.com\gorilla\mux (from $GOROOT)
C:\Users\lenovo\go\src\github.com\gorilla\mux (from $GOPATH))compilerBrokenImport

I have installed gorilla mux using the cmd "go get github.com/gorilla/mux" but I'm getting this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCc9K.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang package is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/packageName)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64448560/golang-package-is-not-in-goroot-usr-local-go-src-packagename)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you didn't run "go mod init" before the "go get".
In cmd, try this:

1. `cd [the dir of your source code]`
2. `go mod init`
3. `go get github.com/gorilla/mux`

For more information run:
`go help mod`
Afterwards, you might also need to restart VS Code.

Answer (score -1):

I had an issue with the same symptoms:
if you only import "gorilla/mux" instead of "github.com/gorilla/mux" in your main.go file the compiler won't be able to incorporate the correct package.

Instead of:

```golang
import (
    "gorilla/mux"
   // other imports omitted for brevity
)
```

Try:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
   // other imports omitted for brevity
)
```